# Unable to connect ot remote DB with ssh tunnel

Tags: java, oracle, jsch

I'm trying to connect to my remote DB with a ssh tunnel, I'm able to achieve this through my DB manager easily but when i try replicating it with my code I'm facing issues,

my SSH connection

```java
   public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = new JSch().getSession("********","1x.xx.xx.xx");
            session.setPassword("*********");
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.connect();
            session.setPortForwardingL(1521,"xx.xx.yy.yy",1521);
            System.out.println("port forwarding completed");
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xx.xx.yy.yy:1521/db","********","********");
            System.out.println(conn.getMetaData().getUserName());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(session!=null) {
                session.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

when i run it i keep getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12541: Cannot connect. No listener at host xx.xx.yy.yy port 1521. (CONNECTION_ID=wIOJk+zFTYCI4FR7XNsHew==)
```

if i change the port to something else i get this (like changing to 1520 [keeping host same])

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: ORA-12541: Cannot connect. No listener at host localhost port 1520. (CONNECTION_ID=On8tBIXKQCu40izLoOLsRg==)
```

and when i try changing the driver host to localhost (or actual machine ip) i get this(i.e changing to both localhost and 127.0.0.1; maintaining the port)

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: ORA-12541: Cannot connect. No listener at host localhost port 1520. (CONNECTION_ID=o8/105qIRG+N9zBuyiaMZg==)
```

Comment: You need to connect to your local port (that is being forwarded). Port 1520 is different from port 1521 (from the error message, which doesn't match your code). You are only forwarding local port 1521 to remote port 1521. You cannot connect to a port that's not forwarded (if it's not forwarded, it doesn't have any listeners).

Comment: I'm changing my Lport accordingly when i'm connecting to my Database, so it's port 1520 when i'm forwarding to it.

Comment: But your code has port 1521. Please [edit] your question to actually show the code that triggers the exception and not some other code that's irrelevant to the error.

Comment: that's my code, the very first error is the error i get during my initial code, other error when i change the values of host and port, i have mentioned that

Comment: and those i have added to show what changes i have done

Answer (score 0):

Starting the forwarding won't magically make the remote IP (xx.xx.yy.yy) available.

You need to connect to the local forwarded port (localhost:1521).

Comment: can you explain this, i'm not getting you. connect how exactly?

Comment: The `DriverManager` connection string should contain `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, not `xx.xx.yy.yy`.

Comment: i have tried with that as well (as mentioned in my 3rd point)

Comment: So edit your question to remove your primary/first nonsense code and focus on what at least might be the right approach.  + Did you try `127.0.0.1` + It's not clear what port did you try to change to 1520 (what ultimately might have broken the code even more)

Comment: the code is meant to demonstrate my basic code and latter points to show if the combination's i have tried (with port's and host's) and yes I have tried `127.0.0.1`, honestly i thought it was pretty clear,  what part is not clear to you? (btw i have made more edit's to make it a bit more clear)